# Error when using useStaticQuery from Gatsby when making GraphQL call

Tags: typescript, graphql, gatsby

We're using Gatsby with Contentful as a datasource. We've setup some microcopy so authors can change and translate parts of the site.

Currently we're getting all the microcopy via GraphQL and then prop drilling which is now getting out of hand. I'm trying to create a ContextProvider where I get all the MicroCopy from our Contentful instance and then wrap it as a Provider eg similar to StyledComponents, ApolloProvider etc and then easily query it.

The ContextProvider is working no problem if I hard code the values or pass a json object in. But when I try to use a GraphQL query (useStaticQuery) I get the following error

[image: Error of useStaticQuery]

this is the code I'm doing

```
import React, { createContext } from 'react';
import { useStaticQuery, graphql } from 'gatsby';

const resourcesQuery = graphql`
  query resourceSet {
    allContentfulResourceSet {
      nodes {
        name
        resources {
          key
          value {
            value
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
`;

interface IMicrocopyContext {
  i18n: any;
}

export const I18nContext = createContext<IMicrocopyContext>({ i18n: {} });

const I18nProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const response = useStaticQuery(resourcesQuery);
  console.log(response);

  return <I18nContext.Provider value={{ i18n: {} }}>{children}</I18nContext.Provider>;
};
export default I18nProvider;
```

Any help as to why this would be happening that would be great.